# How to achieve distributed transactions in the Spring Cloud framework

Tags: spring-cloud

If there are two services A and B that are called by the C service at the same time, save the data. A saved successfully, B failed. You need to roll back the saved A, what is the simple way to handle it?

I hope my friends can give me the simplest way, thank you。

Comment: Spring cloud does not provide any support for distributed transactions

Comment: Is there a good way to do distributed transactions？